# Data binding to singleton class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've searched here a number of times and found a bunch of examples, but can't seem to get anything to work.

I've got a solution set up where a ViewModel refers to a MainViewModel class through a locator. The main view model class has:

```
    public NotifyLog Log
    {
        get { return LogMgr.Instance.Log; }
    }
```

In it. This allows me to specify:

```
 <TextBox IsEnabled="True" Text="{Binding Log.Text, Mode=OneWay}"  />
```

The NotifyLog is defined as:

```
public class NotifyLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public NotifyLog()
    {
        _Log = new StringBuilder();
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private StringBuilder _Log;

    public void Append(String Value)
    {
        _Log.Append(Value);
        OnPropertyChanged("Text");
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _Log.ToString(); }
    } 

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Text;
    }
}
```

For the initial start of the application, the text box is populated but, the OnPropertyChanged handler is never automatically populated by the binding so no changes are detected. I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what...

Thanks for your time,
BlD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to update the log when typing in the text box you need to change the binding mode to TwoWay. also the event is triggered when you exit from the text box, not on each char typed.

if you want to update the text box when the log is changed you need to add a setter to the Text property and raise the NotifyPropertyChanged event (in the setter).

also check the output of the program for some binding errors.

Answer (score 1):

To the line:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="True" Text="{Binding Log.Text, Mode=OneWay}"  />
```

Try adding the "UpdatedSourceTrigger" like so:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="True" Text="{Binding Log.Text, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```